# I get an error when run command `vagrant up` after update Vagrant?

Tags: vagrant

After update vagrant when use command `vagrant up` to work virtual machine i get this error :

```
The VirtualBox VM was created with a user that doesn't match the
current user running Vagrant. VirtualBox requires that the same user
be used to manage the VM that was created. Please re-run Vagrant with
that user. This is not a Vagrant issue.

The UID used to create the VM was: 0
Your UID is: 1001
```

Answer (score 1):

I update the `creator_uid` file in `.vagrant/` folder in my project

1. Open the file should be in this path : `.vagrant/machines/web/virtualbox/creator_uid`
2. And changing the `0` or any value in this file to `1001` because in the error message tell my `Your UID is: 1001`
3. After that `vagrant up` it`s work :)

Comment: 100% correct answer. Fwiw, the .vagrant file is the local one to the project. I was trying to mess with the one in Appdata.